# How to read and replace text in files in python line by line

Tags: python, file, text, replace

I am beginner in python and want to learn how to replace text from different files.

I know how to do it basic, but need help with this:

I have 3 files *main.txt*, *names.txt* and *number.txt*

names.txt looks like this:

```
Anna
Smith
Bob
Jhon
```

number.txt looks like this:

```
1-522-223
1-523-232
1-593-573
1-322-242
```

Line 1 in file names.txt corresponds with line 1 in number.txt (So anna's phone is the first one number.txt, Smith phone is 2nd in number.txt and so on)

Now here is the problem:
The file main.txt looks like this:

```
The person Judy lives in Ontario and has phone number 1-888-2923
The person Michael lives in Toronto and has phone number 1-999-2388
The person Cameron lives in Berlin and has phone number 1-666-2888
The person Douglas lives in Tokyo and has phone number 5-7777-223
```

I know how to find and replace, the problem is I need to change the phone and name on each line in main.txt with the corresponding lines in *numbers.txt* and *names.txt*.
So the edited *main.txt* should be:

```
The person Anna lives in Ontario and has phone number 1-522-223
The person Smith lives in Toronto and has phone number 1-523-232
The person Bob lives in Berlin and has phone number 1-593-573
and so on...
```

I really have no clue how to do it, and the file is pretty big, like 2000 lines of text. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Would you post the code you've written so far?

Comment: Why is the information in three files to start with?  It is too easy to go out of sync, maybe consider using a CSV style file which has the information in different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip each line from each file in one go, update, and write out again. I've used a new file for the output.

```
COL_NAME = 2
COL_PHONENUM = -1

with open('new_main.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    # zip corresponding lines from each file
    for entry in zip(open('names.txt'), open('number.txt'), open('main.txt')):
        main_data = entry[2].split()
        main_data[COL_NAME] = entry[0].strip()
        main_data[COL_PHONENUM] = entry[1].strip()
        outfile.write('{}\n'.format(' '.join(main_data)))
```

Contents of `new_main.txt`:

```
$ cat new_main.txt
The person Anna lives in Ontario and has phone number 1-522-223
The person Smith lives in Toronto and has phone number 1-523-232
The person Bob lives in Berlin and has phone number 1-593-573
The person Jhon lives in Tokyo and has phone number 1-322-242
```

Comment: That's awesome ! Didn't have any idea about zip, just read the documentation and it seems the best approach, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

As number is the last method in main (`[-1]`) and name in 3th(`[2]`) you can split the lines in main and replace `name` and number:

```
with open('name.txt','r') as n:
  names =n.readlines()
  n.close()

with open('number.txt','r') as n:
  numbers =n.readlines()
  n.close()

with open('main.txt','r') as n:
  main =n.readlines()
  n.close()

newmain=[]
for i in main
    for j,k in zip(names,numbers):
         i.split()[2]=j
         i.split()[-1]=k
         newmain.append(i)

newmain=['',join(i) for i in newmain]

with open('main.txt','w') as n:
  main =n.write(str(newmain))
  n.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea what zip does !

Comment: it compress its itrator argument together ! `>>> l=[1,2,3]>>> k=['a','b','c']
>>> zip(l,k)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
>>> 
`

Answer (score 0):

So you have 3 datasets :

- names
- cities
- numbers

Assuming that the relationship between each items of the 3 sets are given by their position (#1 nae goes with #1 city and #1 phone), you will have to

1. extract a list of cities from main.txt (using regex for example)
2. organize your data (list or dict)
3. rebuild a new main.txt using format on a template string

let's go:

```
def extractCities(path_to_main_txt_file):
    '''takes a path to txt file
    returns a list of cities'''

    import re

    with open(path_to_main_txt_file, 'r') as f:
        txt = f.read()

    return re.findall('in (.*) and', l)


def organizeData(names, cities, numbers):
    '''takes 3 lists
    returns 1 nested list'''

    return [[n, cities[names.index(n)], numbers[names.index(n)]] for n in names]
```

Usage

```
>>> with open(r'path/to/names.txt') as f:
       names = f.read().splitlines()
>>> with open(r'path/to/numbers.txt') as f:
        numbers = f.read().splitlines()
>>> cities = extractCities(r'path/to/main.txt')
>>> data = organizeData(names, cities, numbers)
>>> template = u'The person {p} lives in {c} and has phone number {n}\n'
>>> main = [template.format(p=d[0], c=d[1], n=d[2]) for d in data]
```

Now `main` contains a list of strings: you can write it in a new file, overwrite your original file...

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this, I do appreciate and learn a lot from all those different approaches. +1 internet for you !